# To get total price

Tags: android, listview

I am having listview with Srno,Item name,Qty and price.I want to add price and display its total in Textview below listview.I have tried it but its showing me 0 in my textview.When i click on textview its giving me total price in Toast.I have used setText but total price is not displayed in Textview.Following is my code-

**Trial.java**

```
public class Trial extends Activity {
    ListView listnew;

    ArrayList<Integer> sr1;
    ArrayList<String> item1;
    ArrayList<Integer> data;
    ArrayList<Integer> price;

   TextView textViewTotalAmt,textViewamount;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.trial);
        data = new ArrayList<>();
        price = new ArrayList<>();


        listnew = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newlist);
        textViewTotalAmt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.total);

        textViewamount=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.amountdisplay);
        textViewamount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Toast.makeText(Trial.this," "+getTotal(price),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        textViewamount.setText(" "+getTotal(price));



        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        sr1 = bundle.getIntegerArrayList("sr");
        item1 = bundle.getStringArrayList("item");
        data = bundle.getIntegerArrayList("qty");
        price = bundle.getIntegerArrayList("price");

        ArrayList<Integer> qty = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> srn = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> ps = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
            if(data.get(i)>0){
                qty.add(data.get(i));
                name.add(item1.get(i));
                srn.add(sr1.get(i));
                ps.add(price.get(i));
            }
        }



        sr1.clear();
        sr1.addAll(srn);
       item1.clear();
        item1.addAll(name);
       data.clear();
        data.addAll(qty);
       price.clear();
       price.addAll(ps);



        Custom_Trial ct = new Custom_Trial( this,sr1, item1, data, price);
        listnew.setAdapter(ct);
        getTotal(price);

    }




    public int getTotal(ArrayList<Integer> price){

        int total=0;
        for(int i=0;i<price.size();i++){
            total= total+Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(price.get(i)));
        }
        return total;

    }

}
```

Comment: textViewamount.setText(" "+getTotal(price)); this method is called before add any item to price list. set text of textViewamount after adding price elements to list,

Comment: move textViewamount.setText(" "+getTotal(price)); line after getting price from bundle price = bundle.getIntegerArrayList("price");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you shall move this line of code

```
textViewamount.setText(" "+getTotal(price));
```

to the end of onCreate methode

```
Custom_Trial ct = new Custom_Trial( this,sr1, item1, data, price);
    listnew.setAdapter(ct);
    getTotal(price);
    textViewamount.setText(" "+getTotal(price));
```

Comment: This worked well.Silly mistake i made.Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

Your Toast works, because `onClick` happens when all of your items are already inflated.

However, you try to set the value to your TV in `onCreate()`. At the time you call the `setText()`, your `ArrayList` is **NULL** as you only instantiate it. Move the `setText()` at the end of `onCreate()` or after you handle and insert values to `ArrayList`.

OR if you want to display total price only after someone clicks on TV, then paste the `setText()` inside `onClick`, where currently show `Toast` now.